# Identifying sets with subsets of a sum

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Let $(B_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ be a family of sets. For each $\alpha\in I$, there exists a bijection of $B_\alpha$ onto $\{\alpha\}\times B_\alpha$ given by $\phi_\alpha(x)=(\alpha,x)$. This means that the mapping $\phi_\alpha: B_\alpha\rightarrow\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in I} B_\alpha$ is an injection.

For every element of $z\in\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in I} B_\alpha$, there exists a unique $\alpha\in I$ such that $z\in\{\alpha\}\times B_\alpha$; denote it by $\lambda(z)$.

Then $\lambda:\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in I} B_\alpha\rightarrow I$ such that $z\in \{\lambda(z)\}\times B_{\lambda(z)}$, for every $z\in\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in I} B_\alpha$.

Now, I am told to identify $B_\alpha$ with $\{\alpha\}\times B_\alpha$ for every $\alpha$.

Can I now say the following?

> for every $z\in \bigsqcup_{\alpha\in I} B_\alpha$, $\lambda(z)$ is the
>   unique index such that $z\in B_{\lambda(z)}$.

How is this justified?

Let $z\in \bigsqcup_{\alpha\in I} B_\alpha$: then $\lambda(z)$ is the unique index such that $z\in\{\lambda(z)\}\times B_{\lambda(z)}$. Then $\phi_{\lambda}^{-1}(z)\in B_{\lambda(z)}$. In this situation, I understand by "identify $B_{\lambda(z)}$ with $\{\lambda(z)\}\times B_\alpha$" as implicitly saying:

1. "Write $z$ for $\phi_\lambda ^{-1}(z)$ when $z\in\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in I} B_{\lambda(z)}$";
2. "Write $x$ for $\phi_{\lambda(z)}(x)$ when $x\in B_{\lambda(z)}$".

But with this interpretation I still don't understand why $\lambda(z)$ is the unique index for which $z\in B_{\lambda(z)}$. If $z$, here, is going proxy for $\phi_{\lambda}^{-1}(z)$, then this only says that $z\in B_{\lambda(z)}$; it cannot further say that $\lambda(z)$ is unique, because $\lambda(z)$ is not unique for $\phi_{\lambda}^{-1}(z)$ and we are identifying $\phi_{\lambda}^{-1}(z)$ with $z$.

Can someone clarify all this for me, please?

Comment: The disjoint sum  or disjoint union is defined using {a}×B$_a$.   That identify stuff is hokuspokus.  The correct view is  B$_a$ is embedded into the disjoint union as  {a}×B$_a$.